# calculate total price in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react'
import {View , Button , StyleSheet , Dimensions ,ScrollView, 
ViewPropTypes} from 'react-native'
import {
    Text,
    Left,
    Right,
    ListItem,
    Thumbnail,
    Body
} from 'native-base'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from  '../../../Redux/Action/cartActions'
var {height , width}  = Dimensions.get('window')


const Confirm = (props) => {
    const confirmOrder = () => {

    setTimeout(()=> {
        props.clearCart();
        props.navigation.navigate('Cart')
    },500)
}
 var total=0;


const confirm = props.route.params
return (
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={StyleSheet.container}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
             <Text style={{fontSize:20 ,fontWeight:'bold'}}>
                Confirm Order
             </Text>
             {props.route.params ?
             <View style={{borderWidth:2 , borderColor:'orange',marginTop:10 , borderRadius:5}}>
                <Text style={styles.shipping}>Shipping to :</Text>
                <View style={{padding:8}}>
                    <Text>Address: {confirm.order.order.shippingAddress1}</Text>
                    <Text>Phone: {confirm.order.order.phone}</Text>
                    <Text>Full Name: {confirm.order.order.fullName}</Text>
                    <Text>Address 2: {confirm.order.order.shippingAddress2}</Text>
                    <Text>Zip: {confirm.order.order.zip}</Text>
                    <Text>City: {confirm.order.order.city}</Text>
                    <Text>Country: {confirm.order.order.contry}</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Items:</Text>
                {confirm.order.order.orderItems.map((x)=> {
                    
                    return(      
                        <ListItem
                        style={styles.listItem}
                        key={x.product.name} 
                        avatar
                        >
                  
                            <Left>
                               <Thumbnail source={{uri :x.product.image}}/>
                            </Left>
                            
                            <Body style={styles.body}>
                             <Left>
                                 <Text>{x.product.name}</Text>     
                             </Left>
                             <Right>
                             <Text>${x.product.price}</Text>
                             </Right>    
                            </Body>      
                        </ListItem>
                    )     
                }  
                )}
            </View>
           :null }
                        <View>
                     <Text>Total:{total} </Text>
                   </View>
           <View style={{alignItems:'center' , margin:20}}>
               <Button title='place order' onPress={confirmOrder}/>
           </View>
        </View>
   </ScrollView>
   )
}

export default connect(null , mapDispatchToProps)(Confirm);
```

Comment: i need calculate total price

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the sum like this:

```
const total = confirm.order.order.orderItems.reduce((count, item) => count + item.product.price, 0)
```